# Meaning of "All that I ever loved"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> priest was staring hard at something, so
>   Quasimodo followed his gaze.
>   A ladder stood against the gallows. A girl
>   dressed in white was being carried up the
>   ladder. There was a noose around her neck.
>   Quasimodo gasped. It was Esmeralda!
>   Once he reached the platform of the
>   gallows, the man arranged the noose. Then he
>   kicked away the ladder. Quasimodo could
>   scarcely breathe. The girl was swinging from
>   the end of the rope!
>   The priest gave a terrible laugh—such as
>   can come only from one who is not truly
>   human. Quasimodo didn’t hear the laugh, but
>   he saw it and understood. Without thinking,
>   he rushed at the priest in fury and pushed
>   Claude Frollo over the edge.
>   Frollo landed on a narrow ledge before
>   sliding down to a gutter. There he clung to a
>   gargoyle and struggled to get a foothold.
>   Quasimodo had only to stretch out his hand
>   to pull Frollo back—but he didn’t even look
>   at the priest. Instead, he was staring at the
>   gypsy girl. His heart was crushed. A steady
>   stream of tears flowed over his deformed face.
>   At last, Frollo lost his grip. Quasimodo
>   watched as he fell screaming to his death 200
>   feet below. Then he raised his eyes to look
>   upon the gypsy girl. He could see her body,
>   hanging from the gallows. It was twitching in
>   the last struggles of death. Then, in utter
>   despair, he looked down at the archdeacon.
>   With a sob that shook deep in his chest, he
>   cried out, “Oh, **all that I ever loved!** ”
>   Quasimodo disappeared from Notre Dame
>   that very evening.

How we can say this sentence in other words?

Does it mean: the Frollo was the only one who I loved in my life?

or:  The only thing that kept me living now proved to be cruel man?

or: or all that kept me living now disappeared?

Comment: Quasimodo and his story are originally written in French, yes? Perhaps this is a consequence of the translation (it would make a lot of sense of the original quote was something like "O, tout que j'ai aimé dans ma vie!").

Answer (score 1):

The *phrase* means exactly what the combination of the words mean: everything that he has loved, from his birth until now.

From the context, I assume he is lamenting the loss of the *only* thing he has ever loved—Esmerelda:

> There was a noose around her neck. Quasimodo gasped. It was Esmeralda! . . . Instead, he was staring at the gypsy girl. His heart was crushed.

---

Quasimodo pushed Frollo to his death, so it's not him that he loved:

> Without thinking, he rushed at the priest in fury and pushed Claude Frollo over the edge . . . Quasimodo had only to stretch out his hand to pull Frollo back—but he didn’t even look at the priest.

---

So, he lost all that he had loved—and disappeared from Notre Dame. What his disappearance means isn't made clear in the passage quoted. It's likely a matter of speculation more to do with literary criticism than just reading what's here.